# Strange invalid characters error while pushing changes to remote branch

Tags: windows, git

I am using windows machine to push changes in a java file i changed in eclipse.
i am successfully able to commit the changes but when i try to push these changes to remote branch it throws the following error

```
  fatal: invalid characters in /tuscany/jupiter
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried pushing changes via TortoiseGot/GIT UI/ GIT Bash but all of them giving the same error

Comment: Hi @Nocice,

Any more logs?

Would you try egit in eclipse?

Br,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Gitolite on the destination server to which you are pushing to?

- I don't find that error message in the Git repo itself (see [GitHub:git/git search result](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=repo%3agit/git%20%22invalid%20characters%22&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=)), not in Egit repo ([Egit search result](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=repo%3aeclipse/egit%20%22invalid%20characters%22&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=))
- I do however find that error message in Gitolite rpeo (See [GitHub:sitaramc/gitolite search result](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=repo%3asitaramc/gitolite%20%22invalid%20characters%22&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=)), [for instance in `gl-mirror-shell`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gl-mirror-shell#L157).

In which case (Gitolite), make sure the name of the remote repo (see `git remote -v show` output) follows the pattern.

```
$repo =~ s/\.git$//;
$repo =~ s(^/)();
```